# TypeLoadException when Navigating to a page that inherits Page

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm getting a TypeLoadException when I try to navigate to a custom Page.

This is the base class:

```
public abstract partial class MyBasePage : Page
{
    // Some abstract methods and some View-level stuff
}
```

And the other class:

```
public sealed class MyCustomPage : MyBasePage 
{
    public MyCustomPage() : base()
    {
        // Some stuff
    }

    // Methods implementations
}
```

**Note:** I also tried removing the abstract modifier (I replaced my abstract prototypes with virtual methods that simply throw a NotImplementedException, so I get the same result in my derived class), but I still get the same exact TypeLoadException.

This is the message I get:

> "Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation'."

And this is the StackTrace

```
   at System.StubHelpers.WinRTTypeNameConverter.GetTypeFromWinRTTypeName(String typeName, Boolean& isPrimitive)
   at System.StubHelpers.SystemTypeMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(TypeNameNative* pNativeType, Type& managedType)
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
   [...]
```

Am I missing anything? I think I probabily messed something up when I inherited the Page class, but I can't find the error and the compiler doesn't show any warnings whatsoever.

Thanks for your help!

Sergio

**Update:** So it looks like that in Windows Store apps the XAML isn't compiled and the UI is generated at runtime (by parsing the XAML I guess), so it's not actually possible to inherit the XAML.
Is it impossible to do something like that, and do I have to either copy/paste the same XAML in two different pages or to create a single page with different methods depending on the context, or is there another way to "share" the same UI across different pages?
What I need is to get the same exact UI, but with two different classes (I need different types for my navigation method).

Comment: Not sure whether it would compile at all if you didn't, but have you changed the type of the page in the associated XAML file?

Comment: @KooKiz yeah, the name in the XAML file for the base class is the same one it has in its .cs file, and my derived class doesn't have a XAML file instead, it just inherits from the base class and overrides a few methods.

Comment: That may be the problem. You should try a derived class with a XAML file and see whether you have the same issue

Comment: @KooKiz Yup, but the reason I tried to do that was not to copy and paste the same XAML into two different files, as I needed the same UI in two distinct pages. I updated my question :)

Comment: How about using a Template Control (custom control) rather than a Page/User Control?